# How show iframe with content below at FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Now I wrote a standart code for loading iframe in window FancyBox. So I specified type `iframe` and `href` link with youtube params.

```
$.fancybox({
            'type' : 'iframe',
            'maxWidth': "90%",
            'href' : href.replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/') + '?theme=dark&color=white&autohide=1&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1',
            'padding' : 0,
            'margin'  : 0,
            'autoCenter': false,
            'scrolling' : 'no',
            'fitToView' : false,
            'width' : 950,
            'overlayShow': true,

            beforeLoad : function() {
                var template;
                var hash;
                var info;
                getVideo(id);
            },

            afterLoad:function(){
                $('.fancybox-inner').append(template);
                changeURL(matchYoutubeUrl(href)+'#'+id, info.VideoName, info);
            },

            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false
                }
            }
        });
```

I need show **iframe youtube** and after it show any **HTML** code. How to do?
I tried in method:

```
afterLoad:function(){
  // $('.fancy-content').html('<b>Any....</b>');
}
```

But this case clear my iframe...

**Also tried:**

```
afterLoad:function(){
    $('.fancybox-inner').append(template);
}
```

It is works, but I dont see content, its hidden, the block  `.fancybox-inner` has height = 600px, but content is more than 600px, so I dont see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refresh your fancybox (Your iframe needs to be placed inside "fancybox-inner" and display block to make this work) once the iframe is loaded (no need for wait until its loaded if your iframe has a static height).

```
afterLoad:function(){
    $('.fancybox-inner').append(template);

    //resize fancybox
    $.fancybox.update();
}
```

An other solution is, to load your iframe into your `.fancybox-inner`in `beforeLoad`-event function. In that way, the fancybox should size the content right.

Comment: The first solution does not work, can you explain second? The height of `.fancybox-inner` is still 600px after loading iframe. I use version: 2.1.4. Tried also: `$.fancybox.update()`

Comment: I tried now: `$.fancybox.resize();
                $.fancybox.update();` It works, but window in full mode. How to fix?

Comment: @AllenDegrud, please open a new question, cause this is solved and your problem is a new one. Please give my answer the "Tick" -> means right answer. Cheers, Lin

Comment: No, problem is not solved, when I tried you example with resize(), I get a window in full mode.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I accept you answer now, and new question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674879/resize-fancybox-full-mode

Comment: Thanks friend, lets have a look at your new problem :)

Comment: -1 : this answer doesn't solve the problem. You are answering something that the OP already tried (read the question carefully) and doesn't work. How come it's solved? the new question is just addressing the same problem. Additionally `$.fancybox.resize` (the only NEW thing you proposed in your answer) is not a valid method for v2.x

Comment: @lin : no, I am not wrong, and yes, I saw your chat where you are trying "hack" a solution with the wrong options (apart from calling me "idiot" ... but I guess that's the way you address your own flaws insulting people behind the keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fancybox `title` to add any html content you want, you just need to set that html content inside a variable like :

```
var template = 
    '<div id="VideoModalDisplay">' +
    '<p>whatever html content you want to set here</p>' +
    '</div>';
```

... or inside of a (hidden) html `<div>` like :

```
<div id="template" style="display: none;">
    <div id="VideoModalDisplay">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>whatever html content you want to set here</p>
        <p>...etc...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and pull that content inside the `beforeLoad` callback (using the second option) like

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    // some more options
    var template = jQuery("#template").html();
    this.title = this.title ? this.title + template : template;
}
```

Now, based on your **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vjvx6af/1/)**, if you want to call fancybox from this html

```
<div class="play" id="4" data-width="850" data-height="470" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8UVNT4wvIGY"></div>
```

... you may want to tweak it like

```
<div class="play" id="4" data-fancybox-href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8UVNT4wvIGY" data-width="850" data-height="470" ></div>
```

**Notice** I changed `data="{youtube URL}"` into `data-fancybox-href="{youtube URL}"` so fancybox will know where to get the content from.

Also notice that if the URL has this format

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/8UVNT4wvIGY
```

... you don't actually need the `replace()` method to convert it.

After, get the different values (`width`, `height`, etc) from the `data` attributes inside the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    var info = '?theme=dark&color=white&autohide=1&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://whoismed.com&showinfo=0&autoplay=1';
    // getVideo(id);
    var template = jQuery("#template").html();
    this.href = this.href + info;
    this.title = this.title ? this.title + template : template;
    this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
    this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
}
```

**Notice** `this.href`, `this.title`, `this.width` and `this.height` refer to default values of fancybox that can be overridden inside the callback.

Also notice that `this.href` gets its value from the special `data-fancybox-href` attribute (in your html) but we are overriding it to add the *var* `info` with your youtube trailing parameters.

See full code in **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tL26m93L/)**

No need to sweat trying to resize fancybox after adding the content.