# Resize FancyBox - full mode

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

After execution code:

```
afterLoad:function(){
  $.fancybox.resize;
}
```

I get window at full mode, how to fix it?

This is **settings** window FancyBox:

```
'autoCenter': false,
            'autoScale'   : false,
            'scrolling' : 'no',
            'fitToView' : false,
            'autoSize'          :   false,
            'autoDimensions'    :   false,
            'width' : 950,...
```

I use FancyBox version **2.4**

[image] with a currect window full size

**Edited version of question:**

```
function PlayVideo(href, id){
        $.fancybox({
            'type' : 'iframe',
            'href' : href.replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/') + '?theme=dark&color=white&autohide=1&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://whoismed.com&showinfo=0&autoplay=1',
            'padding' : 0,
            'maxWidth': 950,
            'margin'  : 0,
            'autoSize': false,
            'scrolling' : 'no',
            'fitToView' : false,
            'width' : 950,

            beforeLoad : function() {
                var template;
                var hash;
                var info;
                getVideo(id);
            },

            afterLoad:function(){
                $('.fancybox-inner').append(template);
                //$.fancybox.update();
                $.fancybox.resize();
                changeURL(matchYoutubeUrl(href)+'#'+id, info.VideoName, info);
            },

            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us a Screenshot? Cant imagine what realy happens.

Comment: Yes, I attached a screen. I selected area at an red border- it must be size of window fancyBox.

Comment: Join me in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64042/helpyajo

Comment: Lin, I have not 20 reputation to chatting (:

Comment: I did pimp ya up, lets wait some time until you recived it in stackexchange. =) I stay in the chatroom.