# Resize function FancyBox

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

When I use method `resize();` I get FancyBo window at full mode, with a `width = 100%`, although on I set a setting:

```
'width' : 950,
'frameWidth': 950,
```

Comment: You should post your full code... Also according to the documentation resize seems to only have an affect on height, not width...

Comment: Yes, here is a full code: http://jsfiddle.net/0vjvx6af/1/

Comment: I guess your issue was not how to resize fancybox. I think you were mislead. I answered your original question http://stackoverflow.com/a/26682236/1055987 BTW, `frameWidth` is not a valid option for fancybox v2.x